# java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR

Tags: java

I'm getting this null error on this line but I'm doing an `if` check and setting an empty string if null.  Am I doing this wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at form.setSam((teamBean.getHead().getNone().getCode() == null) ? "" : teamBean.getHead().getNone().getSamCode().toString());   //SAM
```

Code:

```
public int show(Action action) throws Exception
{
    HttpServletRequest request = action.getRequest();

    String[] params;

    if (!isEmpty(params[0]))
    {

    String teamNumber= params[0];

    TeamBean teamBean = DAO.getTeamDAO().getTeamByNumber(Long.parseLong(teamNumber));

    Fake form = new fakeForm();

    form.setMoor(teamBean.getHeader().getMoor()); 
    form.setDoor(Double.toString(teamBean .getDoors()));    
    form.setURC(Double.toString(teamBean.getURCS()));   
    form.setUMC(Double.toString(teamBean.getUMCSt()));  
    form.setWeek(Long.toString(teamBean.getHead().getWeek().getnow())); //WEEK
   ERROR HERE -->>   form.setSam((teamBean.getHead().getNone().getCode() == null) ? "" : teamBean.getHead().getNone().getSamCode().toString()); //SAM
```

Comment: What's the point of (jobPlanBean.getHeader().getNsn().getStoresAccountCode() == null) ? "" : "".... You always set it to "", might as well just do setSac("") -- and yes @JB Nizet, I hadn't seen the "ERROR HERE", deleted my first comment when I saw it ;)

Comment: sorry....I wrote it that way for testing purposes....this is how its supposed to look like this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, this is the expression that gives you the `NullPointerException`:

```
teamBean.getHead().getNone().getCode()
```

You aren't checking if `getNone` returns null.

Answer (score 2):

You get it because `teamBean.getHead().getNone()` is null. And since you're calling `getCode()` on this null value, you get a NullPointerException.

Note that

```
form.setSam((teamBean.getHead().getNone().getCode() == null) ? "" : "");
```

could be rewritten as

```
form.setSac("");
```

(except you wouldn't have the NullPointerException)